# Iterating through two list and appending the items together

Tags: python, string, list, loops, for-loop

So I need to append two list together.  Each element of the List one attached to each element of List two.  So it the final list will be something like this: `['L1[0]L2[0]','L1[1]L2[1]','L1[2]L2[2]','L1[3]L2[3]']`.  I keep running into the problem of putting a for loop inside another for loop but the result is having the first loop element repeat multiple times.  I understand this isn't working, if any one can give me a nudge or somewhere to look into information on this sort of subject. As always thank you for the help!! Here is my code:

```
def listCombo(aList):
       myList=['hello','what','good','lol','newb']
       newList=[]
       for a in alist:
             for n in myList:
                   newList.append(a+n)
       return newList
```

Example:

```
List1=['florida','texas','washington','alaska']
List2=['north','south','west','east']

result= ['floridanorth','texassouth','washingtonwest','','alaskaeast']
```

Comment: Post an example along with expected output.

Comment: did you hear about zip?

Comment: I have never heard of zip or been taught this. I will look into this, Thank YOU!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use zip.

```
[i+j for i,j in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Example:

```
>>> List1=['florida','texas','washington','alaska']
>>> List2=['north','south','west','east']
>>> [i+j for i,j in zip(List1, List2)]
['floridanorth', 'texassouth', 'washingtonwest', 'alaskaeast']
```

Comment: clean & pythonic, +1

Comment: I like, though there are a couple other approaches that could potentially go faster on CPython for larger inputs (not usually worth it, but worth noting): `map(''.join, zip(l1, l2))` (wrapped in `list()` on Py3 if you're not just iterating the result once or need a true `list` for some other reason). Or with imports, `from operator import concat`, `map(concat, l1, l2)`, which makes the use line even simpler. :-)

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension over `zip`:

```
[x[0]+x[1] for x in zip(list1,list2)]

>>> [x[0]+x[1] for x in zip(['1','2','3'],['3','4','5'])]
# ['13', '24', '35']
```